# curl return HTTP code 503 when called from a script

Tags: bash, curl

I'm try to call some REST API and get the resulting HTTP code using `curl`. If in a terminal I type :

```
curl -s -o /dev/null -I -w '%{http_code}' -X POST 'http://localhost/gitlab/api/v3/projects?private_token=my_private_token&name=blabla' -H 'Content-Length: 0'
```

It works and return me the HTTP code `201` ("created"). Now I try to use this command in a bash script replacing a part of the url with variable:

```
echo "Enter base URL :"
read gitlab_url # Here I type 'http://localhost/gitlab', to generate the same URL as in first code snippet
code_status=$(curl -s -o /dev/null -I -w '%{http_code}' -X POST '$gitlab_url/api/v3/projects?private_token=my_private_token&name=blabla' -H 'Content-Length: 0')
echo "$code_status"
```

And then it returns me the HTTP code `503` ("Service Unavailable"). To see if there is any differences between the "hard coded" URL and the generated one, I do :

```
echo "curl -s -o /dev/null -I -w '%{http_code}' -X POST '$gitlab_url/api/v3/projects?private_token=my_private_token&name=blabla' -H 'Content-Length: 0'"
# Output :
curl -s -o /dev/null -I -w '%{http_code}' -X POST 'http://localhost/gitlab/api/v3/projects?private_token=my_private_token&name=blabla' 'Content-Length: 0'
```

And if I execute this in a terminal directly, it works and return me `201`. So: why do this command fails if I use it in a script ? Is there anything I missed ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It was a proxy problem. If I use `curl -v ....` I can see the following output:

When `curl` is typed directly in terminal I have :

```
* About to connect() to localhost port 80 (#0)
*   Trying 127.0.0.1... connected
* Connected to localhost (127.0.0.1) port 80 (#0)
```

And when I used it into a bash script I get :

```
* About to connect() to proxy proxy.my.company port xxx (#0)
*   Trying xx.xx.xx.xx... connected
* Connected to proxy.my.company (xx.xx.xx.xx) port xxx (#0)
```

So to fix it I added this in the top of my script :

```
export no_proxy=localhost,127.0.0.1
export http_proxy=""
```

I am very surprised to have to do this, because I already have an environment var `no_proxy` who already reference `localhost` and `127.0.0.1`

Answer (score 1):

Try to run it as `bash -x script.sh`.

Comment: The `bash -x` didn't helped me, but the idea of using debug mod (on curl) helped. Thx